# Debug a service called from android app

Tags: debugging, mobile, genymotion

Is there a way to debug a mobile application (Android) via Visual Studio?

There's a website and a couple of apps that use some services. I have set the solution on my local machine and need to investigate a bug

I've tried to attache VS to Genymotion but it's not working. I know where the issue is located in code, but I need to see what data is send from the mobile app to the backend.

I hope I explained well...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: I wanted to test the backend, and for this is enough to make the API calls with Postman or JMeter. No need for Android Studio or other complicated approach. :)

Comment: Be careful when attaching the process !! VS needs to be attached to the IIS working processes of your application (w3wp) not to the JMeter or Postman. I learnt this the hard way.